# C# Searching All Outlook Folders for MailItem by Subject

Tags: c#, regex, outlook

I am trying to use C# to search my Outlook Inbox (**and all subfolders**) for a MailItem whose subject matches my Regex.

Currently I have this:

```
//InboxItems property
public IEnumerable<MailItem> InboxItems
{
    get
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = 
            outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            return folder.Items.OfType<MailItem>();
    }
} 

//inside method:
string ticketid = "6543165";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^((FWD|RE): ?)*Ticket Diary ?[:-] ([0-9]+ )*\b" + ticketid,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var email = InboxItems.OrderBy(m => m.CreationTime)
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.CreationTime >= createdAfter && rgx.IsMatch(m.Subject));
```

This works great only if the email is in my Inbox folder. However, I want to mimic the *Current Mailbox* search feature of Outlook, not the *Current Folder*.

I have tried creating a `List<MailItem>` of all my subfolder's MailItems but this takes too long to execute.

Is there an efficient way to query the Inbox & subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not ever iterate over all items in a folder or use LINQ with Outlook - this is extremely inefficient.

Use [MAPIFolder.Items.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.find.aspx)/ `FindNext` / `Restrict`.

If you want to search over multiple folders, use `Application.AdvancedSearch` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I found [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) after posting this. I will be using RDO as it will also resolve the security patch issue I've been running into!